# Elastisearch with lots of data and paging

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch to query ES data.

When I query for a page after 10000 element I get this exception:

> RestStatusException{status=400}
> org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.RestStatusException:
> Elasticsearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception,
> reason=all shards failed]; nested exception is
> ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception
> [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed]];
> nested: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception
> [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=Result window is too large,
> from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [12050].
> See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data
> sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window]
> index level setting.]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch
> exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=Result window is
> too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was
> [12550]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large
> data sets. This limit can be set by changing the
> [index.max_result_window] index level setting.]];\n\tat
> deployment.ROOT.war//org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:69)\n\tat
> deployment.ROOT.wa

I've found this: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/result-window-is-too-large/319979 and it mentions about https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after

I thought I could do something similar but... My sort part of the query is:

```
 GET /cars/_search/
  {
   "from": 1001,
   "size": 50,
    
      "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and in the response I have sort block which looks like this:

```
     {
  "took" : 11,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "cars",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1239332",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
        ...},
        "sort" : [
          1.0,
          1.0
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In their example they show search_after with numbers:

```
GET twitter/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "title": "elasticsearch"
        }
    },
    "search_after": [1463538857, "654323"],
    "sort": [
        {"date": "asc"},
        {"tie_breaker_id": "asc"}
    ]
}
```

I don't have any fields by which I want to sort, scoring is the only valid way for sorting, so what should I put in sort part of the query ?

In my example `1.0` in sort block in results is something that does not seem to help me. This is not unique value and search_after it will propably fail, because how Elasticsearch would give me proper results, from 1.0 score  ? What if all are scored by 1.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `tie_breaker_id` field, which is a copy of the `_id` field with doc values enabled. That's going to do the job.

```
"sort": [
    { "_score": "desc" },
    {"tie_breaker_id": "asc"}
]
```

And if you use [PIT (Point in time)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/point-in-time-api.html), another tie breaker field called `_shard_doc` is added automatically for you. For the record, PIT is useful if you want the result set to be "freezed" while paginating, i.e. immune to new documents coming in while pagination is in progress.

Note: `tie_breaker_id` is only available since 8.4 onwards. use `_shard_doc` in earlier versions

Comment: but I dont want to sort my documents by id, but by scores. If i will put it to sort block it will be sorted differently I guess? Can I add tie_breaker_id  only to search_after block and leave sort block as it is, means sort by _score ? Part of my documents may have the same scores.

Comment: If you sort by score, that means you're interested in top scored documents, then why are you paginating further than 10000? can you explain your use case in more details? Also is your index being constantly written to while you paginate?

Comment: Exactly, I would like to sort by score and at the same time be able to age furhter than 10000 elements because that how it was working before I upgraded ES. After upgrade the behavior of ES changed but the application is on production alredy so I dont want to change the product business functionality and I had to upgrade ES. If that is not possible than I will have to inform the customer.

Comment: Can you also answer my second question please?

Comment: When user or some background process is paginating, then new data can be indexed at the same time by some other process. But it was also working like this in past and I don't have to be considerated from business point of view that the new data is somehow ommited, there can be one new document maybe during paging.

Comment: Yes and that's a problem when you paginate by score, because new documents means new scores, so when paginating and new documents come in, all the scores change and you run the risk of missing documents or seeing the same twice

Comment: Yes but it is acceptable that new documents are not included. What is not acceptable or not told to customer is that he now will not be able to page over 10000 elements. Propalby he could live with it but I must be sure that it is only solution and the only alternative the index.max_result_window which is not recommended due to possible efficienty drop. So I understand it correctly :) ?

Comment: Then simply use `search_after` sorting by `_score` and `tie_breaker_id` (in case of same score). I've updated my answer to reflect that. Use PIT if you want the result set to be "freezed" while paginating, i.e. immune to new documents coming in while pagination is in progress.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help :)

Comment: Great, glad it helped!

Comment: Actually one more question, because during implementing it I got: "root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [tie_breaker_id] in order to sort on", I use ES 7.17 and spring data 4.4.15, shouldn't it be available by default ? Should I add it to index directly ?

Comment: Good point, you need to use `_shard_doc` instead of `tie_breaker_id` which is only available from 8.4 onwards

Comment: Thanks again. So last clarification, when using _shard_doc and having multiple shards on Elastic (I don't know what would would be the final configuration on ES on customer premises), would this still work as expected - the results would be properly paged ? or this _shard_doc can be different on different shards and then sorting would bad and paging would fail somehow ?

Comment: `_shard_doc` uniquely identifies each document whatever the shard it is located in, so you're safe