# Paging forward vs backward with PIT

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using ES 7 and spring data to query for data in ES. I want to have paging working after 10000 elements and for that I think I will implement `PIT` and `_shard_doc` approach described here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html I cannot use only _shard_doc, because I got:

> paramValue":"org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Validation Failed: 1: [_shard_doc] sort field cannot be used without
> [point in time];2: [_shard_doc] sort field cannot be used without
> [point in time];

But before I will implement it I would like to understand something fully. Examples show passing `PIT` for the `search_after` approach but they are paging forward and passing last `PIT` to next request. `From` parameter has to be disabled from query, only `size` can be left as I understand from this example:

```
GET /_search
{
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "match" : {
      "user.id" : "elkbee"
    }
  },
  "pit": {
    "id":  "46ToAwMDaWR5BXV1aWQyKwZub2RlXzMAAAAAAAAAACoBYwADaWR4BXV1aWQxAgZub2RlXzEAAAAAAAAAAAEBYQADaWR5BXV1aWQyKgZub2RlXzIAAAAAAAAAAAwBYgACBXV1aWQyAAAFdXVpZDEAAQltYXRjaF9hbGw_gAAAAA==", 
    "keep_alive": "1m"
  },
  "sort": [ 
    {"@timestamp": {"order": "asc", "format": "strict_date_optional_time_nanos", "numeric_type" : "date_nanos" }}
  ]
}
```

If I there should be no `From` on query, then when I am on 5th page how to page backward? My pager has next and back arrows, no numbers. What `PIT` should I pass to retrieve previous page ? Should I cache PIT in my code? But then what about their expiration ? What if `PIT` for the first page would expire during user pagination when user went to 100 page and then he wants to go back the first one ? Would there be some exception ? How may `PITs` can I keep open to be safe and for how long time if I need to cache them ? What is the theoretical count of them that could be safe ?

Comment: If memory serves, you're using Spring Data ES 4.4.15? I think PIT is only [supported](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/2273#discussion_r1019984036) from 5.0 onwards

Comment: Regarding backward paging, you can simply sort desc instead of asc

Comment: Since you said that it was acceptable to [not see new documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77237583/elasticsearch-illegal-argument-exception-reason-result-window-is-too-large-fro) in case they are indexed while the user is paginating, then don't use PIT, just go with search_after paging forth and back, and you won't have any issues, such as timeouts and other stuff you mention.

Comment: Yes, lets assume that new documents are not arriving at all and I am sorting by _score. So, when I would sort only by score, would search_after work properly when half of the documents are scored the same ? I used PIT only because i have exception when using sort by _sort+_shard_doc, because _shard_doc must be accompanied with PIT as the mention exception says.

Comment: True, I advised to use `_shard_doc` as a tie breaker in case some documents have the same score, but `_shard_doc` implies PIT and PIT implies SDE 5.0. So if you can't upgrade, you can use the `_id` field as tie_breaker, but it's not guaranteed to be unique if you have several shards. However, since it's only a tie breaker and the likeliness of having two documents with the same score and the same ID across two different shards is very low.

Comment: I can theoretically upgrade spring-data-elasticsearch libr so that to use _shard_doc and PIT.

Comment: It's always best to not lag too much behind :-)